# Reorganize data in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel

My friend has some data he would like reorganized and I'm wondering the best way to go about it.

[image]

The data looks like this (except with many more drivers), and he would like it to look like this:

[image]

I am unfortunately not too handy with Excel so I imported the data into a Jupyter notebook to use Python (if you have any Excel solutions, I will take them!). My initial thought was to separate the data by each driver, but the only method I can think of is typing each driver name individually and separating it by position, ie. `Gary = data[data['Position']==1]`. But that is time consuming and I am positive not the best way to approach this.

TIA.

Comment: Can you share sample data as clear text instead of an image please

Comment: If there are 100s of drivers, you want 100s of columns? Is each driver doing only 3 laps? If so, wouldn't it be best to have `Driver, Lap 1, Lap 2, Lap 3` so `Gary 82 84 81`, `Bruce 90 91 93` would be better output ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz Yes that makes more sense to me. He requested it be the original way but whatever is easiest for data reorganization. No, there are more laps - average of 20 each.

Comment: Which version of Excel is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know how to read from an excel file. I don't have Microsoft Excel so using csv data to show you how it works.

```
from io import StringIO
excel_data = StringIO('''\
Driver,Lap#,Lap Time(seconds),Position
Gary,1,82,1
Gary,2,84,1
Gary,3,81,1
Bruce,1,90,2
Bruce,2,91,2
Bruce,3,93,2
Scott,1,78,3
Scott,2,92,3
Scott,3,83,3''')
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(excel_data,delimiter=',')
print(df)
df1 = df.pivot(index='Driver',values='Lap Time(seconds)',columns='Lap#')
print (df1)
```

Original dataframe:

```
  Driver  Lap#  Lap Time(seconds)  Position
0   Gary     1                 82         1
1   Gary     2                 84         1
2   Gary     3                 81         1
3  Bruce     1                 90         2
4  Bruce     2                 91         2
5  Bruce     3                 93         2
6  Scott     1                 78         3
7  Scott     2                 92         3
8  Scott     3                 83         3
```

Final DataFrame:

```
Lap#     1   2   3
Driver            
Bruce   90  91  93
Gary    82  84  81
Scott   78  92  83
```

If you do want to print it the way your friend asked for:

You can tweak the `df.pivot` to show as:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='Lap#',values='Lap Time(seconds)',columns='Driver')

Driver  Bruce  Gary  Scott
Lap#                      
1          90    82     78
2          91    84     92
3          93    81     83
```

Note: It always sorts in alphabetic order. So both options for rows or columns for Driver will show up in alphabetic order

If you are using Excel itself, I think there is a much simpler way to address it in Excel itself.

Do Insert Pivot, then under rows, give Driver, under column give Lap#, for values, give Lap Time (seconds). That will give you the same results.

I used Google Spreadsheets. Here's how I got it done:

[image]

[image]